# logging at package level using spring AOP

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, spring-aop, error-logging

I am trying to implement logging and exception framework for my application using spring AOP. I have defined beans for classes in ApplicationContext and using interceptors to log entry, exit and exceptions if any.

My query is : Do I need to create bean for every class in my ApplicationContext or is it possible to generalise this at a package level. If I have 30 classes in my package, I should create 30 beans in my AppContext, rather I would prefer doing it at a package level if it is possible. Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Around` advice. Here define the pointcut such that each class and method of the package are covered / intercepted. See sample below -

```
@Aspect
public class AllMethodLogging {

@Around(execution("* com.x.y..*.*(..)"))
public Object intercept(ProceddingJoinPoint pjp){

    String name = pjp.getSignature().getName();
    try {
        logger.info("started " + name);
        Object obj = pjp.proceed();
        logger.info("finished " + name + " successfully"); 
        return obj;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
         logger.error(name + " finished with Exception - " + t.getMessage());
         throw t;
    } finally {
        // do some more logging if required else skip
    }       
}
}
```

The pointcut `execution("* com.x.y..*.*(..)")` means that any method within `com.x.y` package, and its sub-package, with all visibility should be intercepted by this advice.

See docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) for more examples to customize your pointcut as per your needs.

Comment: I am not using aspectj for some silly reasons even I dont agree with but have to follow.

Comment: thats bad :( hope i could help you here ...Good Luck!